# Finding the root of a basic sequence

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, sequence

The sequence starts with the following:

a<sub>1</sub> = 1, a<sub>2</sub> = 2, a<sub>3</sub> = 5, a<sub>4</sub> = 4, a<sub>5</sub> = 6,
a<sub>6</sub> = 10, a<sub>7</sub> = 9, a<sub>8</sub> = 8, a<sub>9</sub> = 21, a<sub>10</sub> = 12,

a<sub>11</sub> = 13, a<sub>12</sub> = 20, a<sub>13</sub> = 33, a<sub>14</sub> = 15, a<sub>15</sub> = 42,
a<sub>16</sub> = 16, a<sub>17</sub> = 19, a<sub>18</sub> = 63, a<sub>19</sub> = 34, a<sub>20</sub> = 24, ...

Identify the rule of this sequence and the next five terms.

---

The same list of numbers, without indices:

```
1, 2, 5, 4, 6, 10, 9, 8, 21, 12, 13, 20, 33, 15, 42, 16, 19, 63, 34, 24
```

---

Hints are spoilered so that people can choose to solve it without seeing them.

**Hint 1**

> Indices are important. There are two important keywords in the title besides "sequence".

**Hint 2**

> a<sub>26</sub> through a<sub>30</sub> are **27, 78, 29, 84, 31**. Still, your task is to find the rule and the values for a<sub>21</sub> through a<sub>25</sub>.

**Hint 3-1** (continuation of Hint 1)

> One of the two important keywords mentioned in **Hint 1** is "root". What is the notation for a function $f$ applied twice to $x$? How does it relate to the word "root"?

**Hint 3-2** (continuation of Hint 2)

> AnilGoyal's answer is on the right track. Additionally, a<sub>21</sub> = 18, a<sub>36</sub> = 378, and a<sub>63</sub> = 36.

Comment: I am a first timer here.  How should I post answer? directly here or through some other method I mean hidden like your spoiler?

Comment: shouldn't a19 be 51 instead of 34?

Comment: @AnilGoyal No, a19 is 34.

Comment: Can you please recheck it once again. My logic goes exactly upto a17 and it fails at a17? I may surely be wrong but please recheck it once.

Comment: @AnilGoyal I checked the values again and they are all correct under my rule. Added a few more terms under "Hint 2". I do think you've got pretty good progress though.

Comment: I think I have got it! How should I post the answer here?  Can you please share some markdown guidelines

Comment: @AnilGoyal To make a spoiler, put `>!` before each line of text you want to hide in it. To insert some math formulas, you can use MathJax code wrapped inside dollar signs (e.g. `$a_1$` will display inline as $a_1$ and `$$a_1$$` is centered on its own line as $$a_1$$). You can see a preview once you start writing your answer. I (and possibly other experienced users) can fix formatting on your post after you post it, if something goes wrong.

Comment: Please give me one more day (24hrs) to solve this.  I mean please don't post the answer yet

Answer (score 3):

Before I start, consider function $f$ that satisfies $A_x = f(x)$. That is, to find the $x$-th number in the sequence, we can plug in $x$ to $f$.

So we want to find the values of $f(21), f(22), f(23), f(24), f(25)$.

Inspired from hint 2, instead of mapping x to $f(x)$, what if we try to map the relation of $x$ and $f(f(x))$ instead? We get this following pattern.

| $x$ | $f(x)$ | $f(f(x))$ | $x$ in binary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $1$ | $f(1)=1$ | $f(1)=1=1\times1$ | $1$ |
| $2$ | $f(2)=2$ | $f(2)=2=1\times2$ | $10$ |
| $3$ | $f(3)=5$ | $f(5)=6=2\times3$ | $11$ |
| $4$ | $f(4)=4$ | $f(4)=4=1\times4$ | $100$ |
| $5$ | $f(5)=6$ | $f(6)=10=2\times5$ | $101$ |
| $6$ | $10$ | $12=2\times6$ | $110$ |
| $7$ | $9$ | $21=3\times7$ | $111$ |
| $8$ | $8$ | $8=1\times8$ | $1000$ |
| $9$ | $21$ | $18=2\times9$ | $1001$ |

and so on. Based on the provided sequence, it can be said that

> $f(f(x)) = n_x \times x$ where $n_x$ is the number of 1s that appear when $x$ is represented in binary.

That is possibly why $f(f(5))=10=2\times5$ but $f(f(7))=21=3\times7$.

BONUS:

> By constructing the table, we have found that $f(21) = 18$ (row 9). It is exactly as stated in hint **3-2**.

---

From rearranging the function we can obtain a new relation

$f(x)=f^{-1}(n_x\times x)$.

For the values of $x=21,22,23,24,25$, it can be calculated that $n_{21}=3, n_{22}=3, n_{23}=4,n_{24}=2,n_{25}=3$.

Therefore,

> $f(23) = f^{-1}(78)$. Because we know from hint **3-1** that $f(27)=78$, we know that $f^{-1}(78)$ is $27$. Thus, $f(23)=27.$

Finding $f(24)$ is fun because if we try to construct $x, f(x), f(f(x)), f(f(f(x))), ...$ starting from $x=3$, we get the sequence

> $3,5,6,10,12,20,24,40$. So we can know that the value of $f(24)$ is $40$.

So far I can't use $f(22)=f^{-1}(66)$ and $f(25)=f^{-1}(75)$ to my advantage and I'm stuck..

However, I made the connection that the 'root' in title and hint **1** is perhaps meaning 'half-iterate' or 'functional square root', see [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_square_root).

Comment: The rule is mostly correct, and the meaning of "root" is also correct. The reasoning for $f(21)$ and the value of $f(24)$ are correct, but $f(23)$ is not, because $n_{23} × 23 = 92 ≠ 78$. "basic" was referring to "base". You just need a small addition to the rule to define a single sequence.

Comment: @Bubbler Uh yeah that one was my bad. Thanks for catching the error!

Answer (score 0):

It is very clear that -

> If $i$ is power of 2, it is $A_i$ indeed.
>  Thus $A_2$ = 2, $A_4$ = 4, and so on..

Now,

> $A_1$ takes first of the remaining values which is $1$. The sequence cannot be taken any further and hence stops.

Further,

> $A_3$ gets next available value $5$ (some logic seems I am missing here).  This value is used to calculate next $A$ with index $5$ which will be double of previous index.  Thus, $A_5 = 3*2 = 6$, $A_6 = 5*2 = 10$, $A(10) = 6*2 = 12$, $A(12) = 10*2 = 20$, $A(20) = 12*2 = 24$ which reveals our fourth desired number as $A(24) = 20*2 = 40$

Next,

> remaining of our index is 7 thus $A_7$ gets next available value i.e. $9$ here. So $A_7 = 9$.  Similarly, $A_9 = 7(previous index) * 3 (again I cannot figured it out why?) = 21$.  thus, $A(21) = 9*3 = 27$.

Other sequences

> $A(11) = 13$, $A(13) = 33$, $A(33) = 39$....
>  $A(14) = 15$, $A(15) = 42$, $A(42) = 45$....
>  $A(17) = 19$ why not 18?...

From here I got confused and couldn't get it

Comment: You're on the right track. To help you identify the rules behind the multiplier, I added three more terms (to specifically help you with the fourth spoiler block) under Hint 3-2.